# Почему сохранился старый вариант сайта?

Tags: joomla

Дали на изменение сайт, я перестроила его меню и несколько пунктов уже переделала. Из-за глюка в Денвера, переустановила Денвер в другую папку, папку с сайтом скопировала и что вижу: вид сайта по старому, то же меню, отсутствие добавленных мной пунктов. Скритики и файлики для работы с ним остались те, что я и делала. Что такое?
Копия сайта хранится еще в архивном виде на компьютере в документах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пункты меню Joomla хранятся в базе данных. Переустановили Денвер, видимо, со старой БД.

Comment: @sergiks, да только вот поняла тоже это. А новую БД не могу вытащить, так как Денвер был переустановлен из-за слета phpmyadmin-a, экспортировать базу не удалось, а просто перенести из папки data, так там только одна таблица пашет в этом случае. Может есть какие еще варианты восстановить базу?